# Поменял API TOKEN бота, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, aiogram

Доброй ночи, подскажите, пожалуйста, я поменял апи токен бота (чтобы изменить ссылку на бота) и, когда бот оправляет фото выдаёт ошибку:

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.WrongFileIdentifier: Wrong file identifier/http url specified
```

А так бот работает отлично, если апи токен поменять на старого бота, то фото отправляется как надо, без ошибок

Comment: `file_id` уникален для каждого бота и не может быть отправлен другим ботом. Вы должны получить `file_id` новым ботом